# MPI Isend/Irecv performance behavior

Tags: mpi, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

I have a routine named *transfer(int)* which calls MPI routines. In my main program, transfer() is called twice.

```
... // do some work
transfer(1); // first transfer
... // do some work again
transfer(2); // second transfer
```

---

The *transfer(int)* function looks like this

```
... // do some work
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
t0 = clock();
for(int k=0; k<mpisize; k++) {
    MPI_Irecv( (void*)rbuffer[k], rsize[k], MPI_BYTE, k, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, reqs+2*k );
    MPI_Isend( (void*)sbuffer[k], ssize[k], MPI_BYTE, k, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, reqs+2*k+1);
}   
MPI_Waitall(2*mpisize, reqs, status);
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
if (mpirank==0) cerr << "Transfer took "<< (double)(clock()-t0)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " secs" << endl;
```

Note that I only measure the communication time, excluding the pre-processing.

---

For *transfer(1)*, all send and receive buffers have size 0 for each *k*. So essentially, there's no communication going on. Yet, the transfer took 1.95 seconds.

For *transfer(2)*, each processor has to send/receive about 20KB to/from every other processor. Yet, the whole transfer took only 0.07 seconds.

I ran the experiment many times with 1024 processors and the measurements are consistent. Can you explain this phenomenon or what could possibly be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: MPI still requires to do receive ack with zero-byte messages.  First send/recv may be busy setting up comm channels.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on smaller numbers of processors?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MPI performance analysis tool such as [Vampir](http://www.vampir.eu) or [Scalasca](http://www.scalasca.org) to better understand what is happening:

- Are all communications slow or just a few the rest is waiting at the barrier?
- What is the influence of the barrier?

The actual answer highly depends on your System and MPI implementation. Anycorn's comment that zero size messages still require communication and the first communication can have additional overhead is a good start of investigating. So another question you should try to answer is:

- How does a second zero size message behave?

Also MPI implementations can handle messages of different sizes fundamentally different, e.g. by using unexpected message buffers, but that again is implementation and system dependent.